# How to close parent thread on Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I would like to do step by step upload date to web service.
My code:

```
private Thread WebServiceThread;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    WebServiceThread = new WebService();
    WebServiceThread.start();
}

private class WebService extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            new WebServiceUpload().execute("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        }
    }
} 

private class WebServiceUpload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
            // upload part
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //...
            WebServiceThread = new WebService();
            WebServiceThread.start();
            //<Tab>__what to do here__</Tab>
            //...
        }
}
```

Now can run, but cause the device slow.
Please tell me how to close parent thread or restart parent thread way to solve this problem. (or other practice to same target.)

Comment: Which "parent thread" do you mean exactly? The UI thread, the WebService thread or the WebServiceUpload?

Comment: Why would you want to start a new `AsyncThread` from within a new `Thread`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onPostExecute check if thread is running then force it to stop.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //...
            **if (WebServiceThread.isAlive())
                 WebServiceThread.stop();**
            WebServiceThread = new WebService();
            WebServiceThread.start();
            //<Tab>__what to do here__</Tab>
            //...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to chain threads like that. Just create a single `AsyncTask` extension that uploads the data step by step in `doInBackground`. If you want to publish progress reports, you can do that by calling `publishProgress`.

Your method of creating a `WebServiceUpload` from a worker thread is really bizarre and will most likely not work. `AsyncTask` is designed to be started from the UI thread. Just call your `new WebServiceUpload().execute()` from the main thread when you want to start the upload steps.